# Clean method declaration in java

Tags: java, coding-style, annotations

I want to write clean code. So When writing a method I want to inform the caller of a method about parameters, return type, exceptions, etc. When calling a method the caller should already know if the method can return null or if a parameter can be null.

I can explain this in the javadoc but I want to do it with annotations. I know jetbrains and now JSR305 trying to solve this issue but I think they are not enough.

So:

1. Is there any large annotation library for parameters and return types
2. Is this annotation only for only readability of code, or does it throw an exception if an unexpected value/outcome is encountered at run time?
3. Method declarations should include only base checked exception or subclasses of it too like

   ```
   public void foo() throws ConnectionException, AuthenticationException {
   }

   public class AuthenticationException extends ConnectionException {
   }
   ```

Comment: What do you mean "(you) think (JSR305 is) not enough"?  Where does it fall short?  Have you tried using it for your purpose?  It seems to me like you should be able to tag a return type with `@Nullable`

Comment: Think a metod taking two paramater and their type or range depend on each others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might or might not be what you have in mind - design-by-contract annotations allow you to specify that the parameters and return type of a method must meet certain conditions to be considered correct. Take a look at [cofoja](https://code.google.com/p/cofoja/):

> Contracts for Java enables you to annotate your code with contracts in the form of preconditions, postconditions and invariants.
>
> These contract annotations are
>
> - easy to write and read,
> - and checked at runtime.
>
> Annotating code with contracts helps you:
>
> - design,
> - document,
> - test, and
> - debug
>
> your programs.

Comment: Lopez I check  cofoja it can be what i mention but ,Is it bug free and easy to learn.How about its performance .

Comment: @ayengin yes, it's as bug-free as you can expect, and it's being maintained by people from google. Regarding performance, contracts can be turned on or off globally with near-zero performance overhead, so it shouldn't cause any performance problems. Take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Call me old school. But isn't that what javadoc is for?

Comment: Read question again i dont like write javadocs  i  want code a way of self explanator.

Comment: I read your question. Just pointing out that it is a good way of documenting. and a way all programmers are used to. And I didn't now the answer to your question.  PS: Not liking to write javadoc proves your a real programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "3": A method documentation should include all possible exceptions thrown by the method, that is, checked and not checked.

Regarding "2": Annotations are not a mechanism that allows to throw exceptions at runtime. They have three main purposes: generate boilerplate code, documentation and information for the compiler, allowing it to generate warnings. Take a look here:

[Annotations Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)

Comment: Rgearding 2: I think this is not true think about bean validation annotations.Annotation retention policy  can also be run type not only compile time.

Comment: I have never see a metod declaring it throws NullPointerException

Comment: I think me neither, I've taken the advice almost verbatim from Effective Java (Item 62)